# Array of pointers to strings(base type of pointers)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
int main(){
int i;
char *names[]={"pankaj",
               "anshul",
               "dheeraj",
               "rahul"
               };
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("\n%u",names[i]);}
```

When I coded this I found that all the strings are arranged in a contiguous manner. For ex. If names[0]=436, then names[1]=443, names[2]=450, names[3]=458, thus all strings have been allocated memory in a continuous fashion with \0 as a character in between.
     But strings could be allocated memory anywhere and their base addresses be stored in the array of pointers to these strings. Shouldn't be it like  that?
     Moreover What is **base type of these pointers** in the array declared? Are they **pointers to char** Or **pointers to strings.**like are these array of **char(*p)[6]** type of pointers Or array of **char *p** type of pointers.
We can handle the whole strings using this names array like:

```
int main()
{
char *names[]={"pankaj",
               "anshul",
               "dheeraj",
               "rahul"
               };
char *temp;
printf("Original:%s%s\n",names[2]names[3]);
temp=names[2];
names[2]=names[3];
names[3]=temp;
printf("New:%s%s",names[2],names[3]);
return 0;
}
```

In this I could able to reverse the positions of *dheeraj* and *rahul* (as a whole) string by just swapping the base addresses of the strings of the pointer array.
    Through it it looks like that the pointers are *pointer to string* type that is the pointers are pointing to the whole string instead of pointing to the first char of the string only.
   So if they aren't pointers to string and are pointers to char only;  pointing to the first char of their respective strings , how are we able to swap the whole string by swapping only the base addresses of *dheeraj* and *rahul* in the pointer array.

Comment: You need to understand several things: (1) C doesn't really have a "string" type; C simulates strings using arrays of `char`. (2) There is a *very* close relationship between arrays and pointers in C, such that whenever we work with arrays we very often use pointers to do so. (3) There's no such thing as "pointer to string". (4) Even though strings are represented internally as arrays of `char`, due to the close relationship between arrays and pointers, we very often refer to strings using pointers to `char`, or `char *`.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 4):

A literal string is really an array of read-only characters (including the null-terminator). As other arrays they decay to pointers to their first elements. You array `names` is an array of pointers, each pointer initialized as a pointer to the first element (first character) of the literal strings.

When you swap the elements of `names`, you only swap the pointers.

You could easily check the pointers themselves by printing using the `"%p"` format specifier:

```
printf("names[2] = %p, names[3] = %p\n", (void *) names[2], (void *) names[3]);
```

If you do that before and after the swap, you will see that the pointers have been swapped in your array. The contents of the literal strings themselves will still be the same.

The array look something like this before the pointer swap:

```
+----------+
| names[0] | -----> "pankaj"
+----------+
| names[1] | -----> "anshul"
+----------+
| names[2] | -----> "dheeraj"
+----------+
| names[3] | -----> "rahul"
+----------+
```

After the pointer swap the array looks like this:

```
+----------+
| names[0] | -----> "pankaj"
+----------+
| names[1] | -----> "anshul"
+----------+
| names[2] | -\ /-> "dheeraj"
+----------+   x
| names[3] | -/ \-> "rahul"
+----------+
```

The location of the strings themselves are still the same. It's only the contents of the array `names` that have changed.

---

As a small side-note, since literal strings in C are read-only you should really consider them as constant and use `const char *` for pointers to them.

Comment: Here names[2] =450 and names [3]=458. After swap names[2]=458 and names[3]=450.Therefore now d is moved to address 458(dheeraj is the name) and r (first char of rahul) is now moved to 450 address.But why char at 451 which should be h (dheeraj) is changed to a (2nd letter of rahul). If the pointers point to first char of the strings only, only those should be changed and rest chars of strings should stay at their original address even after the swap.

Comment: @VIbhor No no no, you only swap the ***pointers*** in the array itself. You don't copy or move the character inside the strings. See my updated answer, hope it makes you see things clearer.

Comment: oh yes..got it !

Comment: But why strings have got memory in a contiguous fashion? They could have got memory allocated randomly with their base address being collected in the array of pointers.

Comment: @VIbhor That's an implementation detail. How and where the compiler stores literal strings are not specified.

Comment: Everytime they are stored continuously. It feels as if compiler treats it as a 2-d array but with no gaps in between the strings except \0.

Comment: @VIbhor As I said, that's an implementation detail that you can't rely upon.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have a `string` data type as such - in C, a string is simply a sequence of character values including a zero-valued terminator.  Strings (including string literals) are stored as arrays of character type (`char` or `wchar_t` for "wide" strings).

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So given your declaration:

```
char *names[]={"pankaj",
               "anshul",
               "dheeraj",
               "rahul"
               };
```

Each string literal (`"pankaj"`, `"anshul"`, etc.) has type "`N`-element array of `char`", where `N` is the length of each string plus 1 (need an extra element to account for the 0 terminator).  Each literal is stored as an array in memory such that it's available over the lifetime of the program. It's not surprising that they were allocated contiguously, but it's not something to count on.  String literals are *supposed* to be immutable, however the behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined* - it may work, it may not, you may get a runtime error, you may not, etc.

Because they are not the operands of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and since they are not being used to initialize a *character* array, each literal expression is converted ("decays") from type "`N`-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`" (`char *`), and the value of the each literal expression is the address of the first character in the string.  Those pointer values are what's actually stored in the array.

If you hear someone refer to a pointer to a string in C, what they really mean is a pointer to `char` that points to the first character of a string.

So, to summarize:

- `names` is an array of pointers to `char`
- unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, the *expression* `names` will decay to a pointer to pointer to `char` (`char **`), and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array
- each `names[i]` has type `char *` (pointer to `char`)
- each `names[i]` stores the *address* of the first character of each string in the initializer
- the contents of each string literal are stored "somewhere" such that they are available over the lifetime of the program
- attempting to modify the contents of a string literal will invoke undefined behavior - it may work as expected, it may not, you may get a runtime error, you may not, etc.

Your second code snippet only swaps around the pointers, not the string contents - the strings themselves are unmodified.