# Array of pointers pointing to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Can we make an array of pointers in which each pointer is pointing to the whole string? For ex.
           `

```
char names[][7]={"pankaj","sourav","rajesh","sahil"};
char (*pt)[7];
pt=names;`
```

How to make an array of such type of pointers? As I have many 2-d arrays and I want to make an array of pointers (with each pointer of the above type) and each pointer pointing to one 2-d array.

Comment: Put `[]` immediately after the variable name to make an array of the same thing as the variable was... `char (*pt[])[7] = { names, othernames, morenames };`

Comment: Related if not a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56853409/694576

Comment: @alk It is also by the same person

Comment: refer https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-pointers-to-strings-in-c/

Comment: Yeah..got it ! Thanks